# create symfony1.2 existing project new module?

Tags: symfony-1.2

If i create new module in existing project the table is not create and display in  
 command line Application frontend not exist message display

Answer (score 0):

not sure i understand properly your problem; when you create a module, it doesn't create a table (i.e. a database table); it only creates a directory within the modules/ folder of your app (for example frontend/modules); within this directory, it creates an actions folder containing the actions.class.php file, as well as a templates module.

When you want to alter your database, it depends whether you're working with propel or doctrine.

For example, using Propel, what you do is :

- you update your tables and columns definitions in config/schema.yml;
- you run the following scripts :

  - symfony propel:build-model (creates the classes);
  - symfony propel:build-forms (creates the forms related);
  - symfony propel:build-filters (creates the filters);
  - symfony propel:build-sql (creates the new complete SQL file, with the new tables);
  - symfony propel:insert-sql (process the SQL file in your DB — Be aware that it overrides your actual database; if you already have data you wish to save, i recommend that you manually add the tables in your database).